# Convert File path to File Object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to upload file on firebase using JavaScript my file on my server and also have file path but firebase doesn't allow to upload file from file path and it shows the following error message:

```
code_: "storage/invalid-argument"
message_: "Firebase Storage: Invalid argument in `put` at index 0: Expected Blob or File."
name_: "FirebaseError"
serverResponse_: null
```

How can I upload the file or convert the file path to file object?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to upload file in firebase. the uri is the file path which further creates the file type required in firebase.

```
   const uploadImage = async (uri) => {
         const uniqid = () => Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
         const ext = uri.split('.').pop(); // Extract image extension
         const filename = `${uniqid()}.${ext}`; // Generate unique name
         const ref = fb.storage().ref().child(`images/${filename}`);
         const response = await fetch(uri);
        // const blob = await response.blob();
        const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onload = function () {
             resolve(xhr.response);
            };
        xhr.onerror = function (e) {
            console.log(e);
            reject(new TypeError('Network request failed'));
         };
       xhr.responseType = 'blob';
       xhr.open('GET', uri, true);
       xhr.send(null);
     });
     const snapshot = await ref.put(blob);
     blob.close();
     const imgUrl = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
      return imgUrl;
   }
```

after this function you can call this function to upload your Image in firebase database like this,

```
  const formSubmit= async(values, action)=>{
      console.log(values);
      try{
          uploadImage(image) //this is my image upload code
          .then( async(res) => {
             setLoader(false);
             var user = fb.auth().currentUser;
             await user.updateProfile({
               displayName: values.name,
               photoURL: res // use the response url to store in mapped data table
            }).then(function(res) {
                console.log(res)
            }).catch(function(error) {
               console.log(error)
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('it does not work')
            console.error(error)
        })
     }catch(error){
        console.log(error)
     }
}
```